# Simplifying if/else expression

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

How do I simplify this After Effects expression so I don't list each slider separately?
What is the way to write this as an array of numbers between 1 and 5? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
targetLayer = effect("Layer Source For Grid")("Layer");

check = targetLayer.effect("Enable First ROW Control")("Checkbox");

fAj01 = thisComp.layer("BOX").effect("COLUMN control 1")("Slider");// 1st column
fAj02 = thisComp.layer("BOX").effect("COLUMN control 2")("Slider");// 2st column
fAj03 = thisComp.layer("BOX").effect("COLUMN control 3")("Slider");// 3st column
fAj04 = thisComp.layer("BOX").effect("COLUMN control 4")("Slider");// 4st column
fAj05 = thisComp.layer("BOX").effect("COLUMN control 5")("Slider");// 5st column

if(check == 0 && fAj01 == 0 && fAj02 == 0 && fAj03 == 0 && fAj04 == 0 && fAj05 == 0) {
    100;
} else {
    0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
targetLayer = effect("Layer Source For Grid")("Layer");

const numbers= = Array(5)

const check = targetLayer.effect("Enable First ROW Control")("Checkbox");

const sliders = numbers.map(num => thisComp.layer("BOX").effect("COLUMN control " + (num + 1))("Slider"))

if(check == 0 && sliders.every(slider => slider == 0)) {
    100;
} else {
    0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Konrad,
Hmm, it doesn't give me any errors (after I fixed slides.map to sliders.map) in After Effects but it doesn't perform what I expected. I was expecting if any of 5 sliders are anything other than 0 to trigger if/else "0". Maybe problem is that After Effects JavaScript is just Adobe's version of JS so some of the functions are not recognized like map or every. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @gnugnushka my bad, I fixed the code

Comment: No problem. Thank you. It still not working as expected in after effects. There are no errors but this expression is applied to the layer transparency and unfortunately, it does not switch to 0 transparency if any of the sliders is different than 0. Are you familiar with After Effect expressions? Do you have any ideas why it is not working? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure `map` and `.every` work with expressions in AE. Here's one that uses more basic syntax

```
const targetLayer = effect("Layer Source For Grid")("Layer");
if (targetLayer.effect("Enable First ROW Control")("Checkbox")){
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        if (thisComp.layer("BOX").effect("COLUMN control " + i)("Slider").value !== 0){
            return 0
        };
    }
}
100;
```